# Force image download - .php files download

Tags: php, wordpress

this is my download.php;

```
session_start();
$file = $_GET['file']; 

    download_file($file); 
function download_file( $fullPath ){

  // Must be fresh start
  if( headers_sent() )
    die('Headers Sent');

  // Required for some browsers
  if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

  // File Exists?
  if( file_exists($fullPath) ){

    // Parse Info / Get Extension
    $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);

    // Determine Content Type
    switch ($ext) {
      case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
      case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
      case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
      case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
      case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
      case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
      case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
      case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
      case "jpeg":
      case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
      default: $ctype="application/force-download";
    }

    header("Pragma: public"); // required
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
    header("Content-Type: $ctype");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$_REQUEST["isim"]."\";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile( $fullPath );

  } else
    die('File Not Found');

}
```

This is forced jpg download file. But this file can download all .php files.

Normaly i use this download link and download image;
http://domain.net/download.php?file=wp-content/uploads/2016/04/10/126379-fantasy_art.jpg

But then i tested this link download my config file...
http://domain.net/download.php?file=wp-config.php

I think this is big vulnerable.

How can i fix this? i dont want download any .php files...

Thanks..

Comment: "I think this is big vulnerable." Yes... yes, very. Good that you caught it. The easiest solution would be to make sure only files within a certain directory are okay, and match the `$fullPath` variable against that before sending anything back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use default in your switch case to avoid this problem:

Remove this:

```
default: $ctype="application/force-download";
```

For this: `default: die('File not found');` or `default: return false;`

Also you could check if path makes sense, like it should be a subfolder of `uploads`. This post has some info for you: [Test if a directory is a sub directory of another folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628699/test-if-a-directory-is-a-sub-directory-of-another-folder)

Comment: thanks mate. and i add "default: die('File not found');" now works good. thanks a ton !

Comment: thanks mate. i replace "default: die('File not found');" this code. now work fine...

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be good for you to step back and consider what this script actually does, because it is still a gigantic security hole.  Here is what it does:

1. Take the user's input (which is always untrustworthy)
2. See if it's extension is allowed according to a small list of possible extensions
3. If so, pass it off to the user

Now that you have it die for unrecognized file extensions, it won't let them download your actual php files.  But it will still let the user do all sorts of terrible things, all of which comes down to one very key issue:

**You make no attempt to verify that the file being requested is actually reasonable for the person to view!!!**

A key point is that readfile() doesn't care where the file is.  Nor does it even assume that the file is in your website's public directory.  The only reason it is downloading files from your web directory is because you didn't start the filename with a slash.  However, readfile() will happily pass along anything on the server that it has read access to.  Without your recent change a user could have just as easily done this:

http://domain.net/download.php?file=/etc/passwd

Moreover, it doesn't even have to be an actual file on the server.  In most PHP installations PHP will happily load up URLs as actual files.  So someone could also use your script as a proxy:

http://domain.net/download.php?file=http://theFBIwillArrestYouIfYouLoadThis.com/secrets.pdf

That sort of vulnerability (the ability to use your script as a proxy) is still present in your current solution.  Anytime I see a website take file paths like this I *love* to see just how much it will let me get away with.  You could set yourself up for a world of hurt in the worst case scenario.

You have to look at it from a defense-in-depth scenario.  What it boils down to is the difference between blacklisting (what is the user not allowed to do) and whitelisting (what should this user be allowed to do).  Good security practices rely on the latter method of thinking exclusively, because it is impossible to come up with a completely exhaustive blacklist that covers all possible scenarios.

In a case like this if you want a user to be able to download files you need some sort of list of files that are allowed to be downloaded.  One example would be to place any file that is supposed to be downloaded into a specific directory.  If a user requests a file then your script can use realpath() to make sure that file is actually in your public directory and otherwise forbid the download.  Although if they are all in one directory you could just as easy change a configuration rule in your webserver (e.g. apache or nginx) to have it automatically add the 'content-disposition: attachment' header to anything in that directory.  Then you just have to make sure that you never put the wrong files in that public directory.

Me personally though, I would approach it with a complete white-list.  I would never let someone specify a filename and then use it to download a file.  Rather I would have an administrative area where I manage files that are marked for download: the list of allowed files would be stored in the database and managed by me.  When the user downloads a file they don't do it by specifying a filename but rather by specifying the id from the database that corresponds to the file they want to download (a simple user interface is necessary to facilitate this).  The ID is used to lookup the file path, and the file can then be downloaded safely.  You can then even store the files in directories outside the public area of your website so that you have full control over who can access the files.

That last suggestion is probably overkill for what you are trying to do, but the short of this is simple: you have to think carefully about the security implications of your code and make sure you are giving the user the minimum amount of privileges possible.